# Why we need to contemplate over Quran?

Tags: quran

In Quran, Why Allah has repeated again and again for pondering over Quran.

Comment: As usual question as a one liner! Please spend some time in asking a well formulated question. Rather than asking questions you already have your own answer for. Note that this question also is rather subjective and therefore a bad fit for the site.

Comment: You should elaborate your question, for it to get satisfactory and beneficial answers. My tip would be to add references to *" Allah has repeated again and again for pondering over the Quran. "* claim and avoid one line questions.

Comment: The necessity to contemplate is only fard kifayah and your questions are generally not well-posed, no clear focus, no much information about a prior research effort it always feels like you want to ask a question that only you can answer because only you know what you are expecting the answer to be this is not how this site works.

Comment: Jamila, its not like that I only expect that only, I can answer the question and no body else.  As I am not a scholar. The thing is that I was mesmerized by these thing and just draw other attention with the intention that may be they also mesmerize in the same way. If anybody else add further information in it. then its my pleasure. As I have not restricted anyone. In fact, I am also eager to have more knowledge in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

> “***This is a Blessed Book that We have revealed to you so that the wise may ponder over its Verses and seek direction and guidance***.”
>
> (Saad:29)

Being a magnified speech of Allah Subhan Tallah, Quran is great in goodness, rich in blessings, and abundant in gifts! That is why Allah repeats again and again in Quran:

> **وَلَقَدۡ يَسَّرۡنَا الۡقُرۡاٰنَ لِلذِّكۡرِ فَهَلۡ مِنۡ مُّدَّكِرٍ**
>
> ***“And We have indeed made the Quran easy to understand and remember, then is there any that will remember (or receive admonition)?”***
>
> (Qamar: 17, 22, 32, 40)

In Arabic, the word يَسَّرۡنَا is used for such things which are ready to use and needs no further preparation. So, Quran is:

> ***“This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those conscious of Allah*** "
>
> (Al Baqarah: 02)

At the same time, Allah has given all of us the ability of مُّدَّكِرٍ (thoughtfulness or to understand things deeply). Allah has never mentioned anywhere in Quran that to investigate and research upon Quranic Ayat is only the duty of imams and scholars. If you consider yourself a wise person then you have no exemption in this regard.

Now, the question arises that, is there any reason left to blindly follow them? Blind following has become a major reason for current Firkahs in our society.

> ***“Then do they not reflect upon the Qur’an? …..”***
>
> (Nisa 82)

Because, we have wrapped up the Quran and placed it in high shelfs as a sacred thing. We open it only for barkaat, sawab, wazaif, dispelling the ghosts and other advantages and rarely try to understand the message it contains.
Anyhow, we all just need to develop a companionship with Quran. We all know that companionship requires continuous adherence and mutual understanding. Same is the case with Quran It requires reciting, listening, pondering, learning it repeatedly and reflecting over its meaning on a daily basis. Whoever recites the Qur’an one day or abandons it for several other days or only open it in Ramzan, is not a companion, even if he is a memorizer of the Qur’an.

No doubt, an imam or a common man is equally rewarded for listening or reciting Quran. But pondering over the Qur’an is a higher degree on the path of companionship. Because deeper understanding led us to uncover the hidden treasures, secrets, and wisdoms in Allah Subhan Tallah speech. It’s like when we sip a drop of water, we never see even a particle of dust in it. But while exploring it through a telescope, we found a world of tiny organisms in it. In the same way, we just need to use our wisdom to contemplate over Quranic ayah, if we want to become close to our lord as a friend.

It was narrated that Anas bin Malik said:

> ***"The Messenger of Allah said: 'Allah has His own people among mankind.' They said: 'O Messenger of Allah, who are they?' He said: 'The people of the Qur'an, the people of Allah and those who are closest to Him."***
>
> (Ibn Majah 215)

To attain the above-mentioned positions, Quran has an open invitation for all of us.

> ***“…… then is there any that will remember (or receive admonition)?”***
>
> (Qamar:15, 51)

Comment: Please use the formatting tools, as of right now it might be hard for others to really know what you have a quoted. Use > before quoting

Comment: The clearness of Qur'an was partially abrogated by the first unclear verse.